# How we can get console output in jenkins job 'createhosts' log output instead of showing build number in jenkins build pipeline project?

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, console-output, build-pipeline

I wrote a pipeline script and in console output i need createhosts log output also instead of showing build number.

Script:

```
pipeline {
    agent none
    stages {
        stage('create hosts') {
            steps {
                echo "Hello! , This build for create VMs "
                build job: 'createhosts',
                 parameters: [
                *********
        ********* some parameters
        ]
            }

        }
        stage ('CD job ') {
            steps {
                echo "This build for configure VMs "
                build job: 'CD'
            }
        }
        stage ('Delete VMs') {
            steps {
                echo "This job is required a host file as input for approval to Delete VMs"
                input "approve for deletion"
        build job: 'delete_vms'
        }
        }
    }
}
```

[image: click here for output image]

Comment: If you want the log output in this build then do the work in this job, don't spawn a whole other job.

Comment: Thanks Quantic, but that is difficult to do all that job work to here, spawn is better option to me, and I  need log output here,

Comment: I found answer, before build a job , assign into a variable, def bRun =  build job: 'vsphere_createhosts', parameters: [ ****************** ], and print it using : println bRun.rawBuild.log,  but I need console output while running job, not after completion ,

Comment: while running job itself I need console output real time,

Comment: Advantage of doing it in a different job is easier to rerun the specific job if its failed. Unfortunately Jenkins pipeline doesnt have an option at this time of writing to rerun a specific stage until this is solved - https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-33846